# List of timestamps overrides the previous timestamp

Tags: java, timestamp

I am using an arraylist to store list of timestamps of past 5 weeks.

```
   i.e., if today is 2014-06-09, I want to store 
   2014-06-02 
   2014-05-26 
   2014-05-19 
   2014-05-12       
   2014-05-05
```

Here is my code.

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String ap[]) throws InterruptedException{
List<Timestamp> ts = new ArrayList<Timestamp>();
Timestamp t = new Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime());
Timestamp temp = null;

for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    t.setTime(t.getTime()-(7*24 * (long)60* (long)60) * (long)1000);
    temp = t;
    System.out.println(t);
    ts.add(temp);
    temp = null;
        }
}
}
```

But the problem is always I am getting the list of overrided values i.e., list contains all the elements as last timestampI i.e 2014-05-05)
Can anybody reply to this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're not getting "new" timestamps is because you keep overriding the same one and adding it to the list - so you end up with the same object entered 5 times to the list and the last value will display in "all" the items. You don't need `temp` - simply create a new `Timestamp` object and add it to the list:

```
    List<Timestamp> ts = new ArrayList<Timestamp>();
    Timestamp t = new Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime());

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        t.setTime(t.getTime()-(7*24 * (long)60* (long)60) * (long)1000);
        System.out.println(t);
        ts.add(new Timestamp(t.getTime()));
    }
```